# Does a Crashlytics-like service for web app exists?

Tags: javascript, php, web-applications, web, crashlytics

I am a web and iOS developer. On mobile, we have famous tools to collect all the exceptions and errors that application throws.

There's Crashlytics (and others) that, with few lines of code to install the sdk, start tracking everything automatically. Then they display the error and useful information on their website with priority and other stats.

Is there anything like that for web applications? Or explicitly for php or js apps?

Comment: you asking web analytics means try this http://loggr.net/

Comment: I don't think Loggr is the solution for that. From their 'How it works' page: "What it's not
Loggr is not for web traffic. Use Google Analytics for that. Loggr does not replace syslog or windows event viewer. Use Splunk for that. We do high-level events like errors, sales, usage, job activity, etc."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[www.exceptional.io](http://www.exceptional.io) is exactly what you're asking for. It costs $9 per month after a free trial.

Integration with PHP is done by including a wrapper and a couple of lines of code:
https://github.com/ankane/exceptional-php/

It can also be integrated with javascript with a couple of lines:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.exceptional.io/exceptional.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  Exceptional.setKey('your_api_key');
</script>
```

Another option is New Relic, although it does a lot more than purely error logging - it provides all kinds of server monitoring metrics.
https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/applications-menu/errors-dashboard

Comment: Wow, Exceptional seems great! I'll test it right away!

Comment: Just here to add that nowadays, this solution costs $49/month and renamed to Airbrake.

Comment: @Baksteen Wow, that's quite a cost. I'm getting away with using Sentry.io on the free plan now, though that won't be suitable for bigger operations.

Comment: Update: This solution now costs $59 per month and goes upto $599 for top plan

Comment: Seems the domain / website www.exceptional.io is no longer active.

Comment: @Abhi yeah Exceptional acquired Airbrake and merged the two, under the name Airbrake. Refer to the newer answers above for more up-to-date recommendations

Answer (score 33):

There's was a great discussion on this topic by Paul Irish on Google+ https://plus.google.com/+PaulIrish/posts/12BVL5exFJn (No longer available after Google+ closed). But here is the summary of that post.

Some of the services mentioned:

- bugsense.com
- jslogger.com
- qbaka.com
- muscula.com
- errorception.com
- exceptionhub.com
- bugsnag.com
- exceptional.io
- airbrake.io
- getsentry.com
- github.com/Offbeatmammal/jsErrLog - open source
- github.com/occ/TraceKit - most comprehensive stacktrace library

Comment: I tried a few of these today (bugsnag, rollbar, and sentry), and sentry seemed to be the best (and no, I'm not affiliated). Bugsnag was nice, but seemed to miss certain test errors I triggered. And rollbar (which isn't listed here), I didn't like the user interface as much.

Comment: Good list. I recommend Sentry these days - I'm using it for JavaScript.

Comment: Another one that can be added to the list is Datadog

Answer (score 4):

Future users may find following useful.

[Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) is a Crashlytics like solution for [lots of platforms](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/)

- Web front-ends and their frameworks / libraries like React, Angular, Vue.
- Back-ends languages and their runtimes / frameworks / libraries like Rails, Express, Lavarel.
- [Serverless platforms](https://sentry.io/for/serverless/)
- [IoT](https://sentry.io/for/iot/)
- Mobile clients including frameworks like React Native, Flutter.
- [Desktop platforms](https://sentry.io/for/native/) ex: MacOS, Windows, Linux
- [Gaming platforms](https://sentry.io/for/gaming/) ex: Unity, Unreal
- [Data](https://sentry.io/for/data/)

In addition to error reporting it also support [performance monitoring](https://sentry.io/for/performance/).

More than anything it is a [fully open sourced product including the both client and the server, not just opensource core.](https://sentry.io/_/open-source/) So it can be fully self hosted.

---

Note : I am not affiliated with Sentry in anyway.